# Command subsitution in bash without backticks

Tags: bash

If I normally have to write:

```
echo `someCommand`
```

...in order for someCommand to be executed and its output to be sent to echo. Is there some way I can instead write:

```
echo someCommand
```

...and get the same effect - ie: no backticks?

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
echo $(someCommand)
```

Instead of backticks, if it's just backticks you don't like.

Comment: I was hoping to save myself the extra keystrokes :) Any alternatives?

Comment: @Taras: Nope, this is the only other way.